# How to launch customized form from code in Epicor ERP 10?

Tags: customization, epicorerp, epicor, epicor10

I’m working on customization where I prepared customized Customer form and Case Entry form.
In the Case Entry I have button that should launch customized Customer form.
Is it any other way to do it than adding new menu item for customized Customer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly, a very similar question was asked on EpiUsers: https://www.epiusers.help/t/launch-customized-form-code/62207/5

Here's a snippet from the post. The link gives a lot more info with screenshots:

> You can always create a New Menu ID under Processes section of the tree in Menu Maintenance, so it won’t show up on Menu selection, but then you can call it via code.
>
> Is there a way to call it without adding it, I am sure one could debug what Epicor calls when you enter Customization Mode and select a layer. **I believe its possible, I just haven’t taken the time to debug it, because I always use the Menu Maintenance instead, because layer names change and relying on a special layer name is more fragile than adding a Menu Item under Processes section in Menu Maintenance** – Plus then you can re-purpose the same Menu ID everywhere easily, without hardcoding layer names.

This way, you can keep the standard Customer form in place on the menu, but use the button to launch the customization. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! It was me who started this topic on EpiUsers :D

Comment: Haha! That's awesome. Your post helped me out with a similar issue so I just thought I would share the knowledge :)

Comment: EDIT - just realized that you were also the poster of this question... lol my fault man